# Rails only the first line of my after_create function is called

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to dynamically generate an example survey when a user is created. The after_create function seems to be getting called as the `Survey` is created but the `Questions/Answers` aren't being created. Any idea why they aren't being created?

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  after_create :example_survey
  has_many :surveys

  def example_survey
    survey = Survey.create(title: "Example Survey", survey_limit: 500, number_taken: 376, status: "In Progress", user_id: id, completion_date: Date.today + 14)
    genderQuestion = Question.create(title: "What's your sex?", single_response: true, survey_id: survey.id)
    answer1 = Answer.create(title: "Male", question_id: genderQuestion.id)
    answer2 = Answer.create(title: "Female", question_id: genderQuestion.id)
    ageQuestion = Question.create(title: "What's your age?", single_response: true, survey_id: survey.id)
    answer1 = Answer.create(title: "14-17", question_id: ageQuestion.id)
    answer2 = Answer.create(title: "18-24", question_id: ageQuestion.id)
    answer3 = Answer.create(title: "25-34", question_id: ageQuestion.id)
    answer4 = Answer.create(title: "35-44", question_id: ageQuestion.id)
    answer5 = Answer.create(title: "45-54", question_id: ageQuestion.id)
    answer6 = Answer.create(title: "55+", question_id: ageQuestion.id)
    incomeQuestion = Question.create(title: "What's your household income?", single_response: true, survey_id: survey.id)
    answer1 = Answer.create(title: "<30,000", question_id: incomeQuestion.id)
    answer2 = Answer.create(title: "30,000-50,000", question_id: incomeQuestion.id)
    answer3 = Answer.create(title: "50,001-80,000", question_id: incomeQuestion.id)
    answer4 = Answer.create(title: "80,001-110,000", question_id: incomeQuestion.id)
    answer5 = Answer.create(title: "110,001-150,000", question_id: incomeQuestion.id)
    answer6 = Answer.create(title: "150,001+", question_id: incomeQuestion.id)
  end

end
```

Comment: `logger.debug(genderQuestion.valid?)` - maybe you're ignoring some constraints that need to be satisfied.

Comment: http://apidock.com/rails/v4.0.2/ActiveRecord/Relation/create!

Comment: Check validations, there might be some validations that are getting failed.

Comment: The validations seem fine - I just require an age and survey_id/question_id respectively. I just tried pasting it line by line into the console and everything worked as I'd expect it to. So the code seems to run correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I did a `rake log:clear` and added @Amadan's logger statement into my code and it just started working. Not sure what changed, but it works now :).